# Check any of the columns contains character from a string

Tags: sql-server, in-clause

I have for columns in a table which contains values like this

```
class1   class2   class3   class4
A        D        0        0
0        A        B        0
B        0        0        C
A        0        D        0
```

And I have strings like `First="A,B"`, `Second="C,D"`

How do I check any one of the character from the string contained in any of these four columns

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable where class1 in('A,B,C,D')
UNION
select * from yourtable where class2 in('A,B,C,D')
UNION
select * from yourtable where class3 in('A,B,C,D')
UNION
select * from yourtable where class4 in('A,B,C,D')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it takes time

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from t 
where 

'A,B' like '%'+class1+'%'
or
'A,B' like '%'+class2+'%'
or
'A,B' like '%'+class3+'%'
or
'A,B' like '%'+class4+'%'
```